# Send game invite without using Game Center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm wondering if someone could tell me how apps like Wordfeud and Draw Something send game invites? I'm assuming they're not using Game Center. Do they use push notifications to do this? If so, how do they handle if the user does not accept push notifications for the app?

The app Rumble handles game invites without using Game Center or Push Notifications. Do they handle invites as session, on the server side?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do use push notifications and the answer to how they handle abscence of those is: not at all. There is simply no way to do so (except maybe sending an email for every invite, but meh).

Comment: I edited my question, I don't think what you're saying is correct.

Comment: okay i thought you were referring to handling invites when the app is closed. when the user opens the app, my best guess would be they just query some custom webservice for game invites for the currently logged in player of for a player id that was generated by the app or something like that